# Woocommerce категории товаров. Как редактировать метатеги для SEO?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, woocommerce

Плагин All in One SEO не позволяет редактировать метатеги (title, keywords, description) на странице категории товаров.

Какие есть способы сделать это через плагин?
Через редактирование php файлов woocommerce?

Comment: Чего он не позволяет редактировать? http://take.ms/K2QyA

Comment: Что это у вас за плагин? Yoast SEO Premium?

Comment: Нет, самый обычный. Вверху справа на админ странице товара есть Настройки экрана. Поставьте там галочку возле Yoast SEO

Comment: Причём тут Yoast? В вопросе чётко видно какой плагин(ы) используется..

Comment: вечно я их путаю. два молодца, одинаковы с лица

Answer (score 1):

> Какие есть способы сделать это через плагин? Через редактирование php файлов woocommerce?

Для этого есть расширение для All in One SEO: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-all-in-one-seo-pack/